# `can't resolve reference` eslint warning with react preset

Tags: reactjs, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I get the following warnings on every eslint run with config following config. What is it caused by and how do I get rid of it?

eslint warnings

```
can't resolve reference #/definitions/basicConfig from id #
can't resolve reference #/definitions/basicConfigOrBoolean from id #
can't resolve reference #/definitions/basicConfigOrBoolean from id #
```

.eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  extends: 'airbnb',
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    jest: true,
  },
  plugins: ['react', 'jsx-a11y', 'import', 'jest'],
  rules: {
    'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': ['error', { devDependencies: true }],
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': [0],
    'import/prefer-default-export': [0],
  },
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      webpack: {
        config: 'webpack.config.js',
      },
    },
  },
  parser: 'babel-eslint',
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was caused by `eslint-plugin-react` package (which I found out following [this airbnb config issue](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/1488)).

[This PR](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/pull/1292) solves the issue and contains more info. [The gist](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/pull/1292#issuecomment-321396710) is that it was **fixed in version 7.2.0** of the `eslint-plugin-react` package, so all I needed to do was `yarn upgrade eslint-plugin-react`.